# TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_id' in [mongoose, body-parser, ./config]

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I keep getting the error message "TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_id' in " + "mongoose", "body-parser", "./config"... apparently any dependency at all. I have tried:

- Making sure my models/schemas are correct, as suggested here: [TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_id' in male](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985434/typeerror-cannot-use-in-operator-to-search-for-id-in-male)
- Commenting out any mentions of req.body completely, so as to avoid any possibility of that causing an error, as referenced here: [TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_id' in [{}]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27577099/typeerror-cannot-use-in-operator-to-search-for-id-in) and here: [Mongoose TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_id' in [object Object]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17089958/mongoose-typeerror-cannot-use-in-operator-to-search-for-id-in-object-obje)
- Read this but don't even know what is going on here: [Mongoose TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_id' in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29349724/mongoose-typeerror-cannot-use-in-operator-to-search-for-id-in?rq=1)
- I tried commenting out parts of the config.js file that I thought might be causing the problem. (see below)
- I have even tried commenting out the offending dependencies completely (commented out the `var config = require('./config')`, for example), which obviously is not a viable long-term solution but also did not get rid of my error. Instead, this just moved the error to a different dependency (e.g., now it's taking issue with mongoose itself).

So now I'm stumped.

Here is my user model:

```
"use strict";

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: false},
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: false}
});

var user = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);

module.exports = user;
```

Here is my server.js:

```
"use strict";

var require = require('./models/user');
//var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
//var config = require('./config');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
//app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static('public'));

var runServer = function (callback) {
    mongoose.connect(config.DATABASE_URL, function (err) {
        if (err && callback) {
            return callback(err);
        }

        app.listen(config.PORT, function () {
            console.log('Listening on localhost:' + config.PORT);
            if (callback) {
                callback();
            }
        });
    });
};

if (require.main === module) {
    runServer(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    });
};


app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req);
    //console.log(req.body.password);
    user.create({
        username: 'Test',
        password: '1234'
        //username: req.body.username,
        //password: req.body.password
    }, function (err, user) {
        if(err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                message: 'Internal Server Error'
            });
        }
        res.status(201).json(user);
        console.log(user);
    });
});

exports.app = app;
exports.runServer = runServer;

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

Here is my config.js file:

```
exports.DATABASE_URL = process.env.DATABASE_URL || global.DATABASE_URL 
|| 'mongodb://demo:demo@ds121483.mlab.com:21483/job-tracker-data';
//exports.TEST_DATABASE_URL = process.env.TEST_DATABASE_URL ||
    //'mongodb://demo:demo@ds121483.mlab.com:21483/job-tracker-data';
exports.PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
```

And here are a sampling of the error messages:

```
/home/meryem/DevStuff/code/job-tracker-capstone-
app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:212
      if (obj && '_id' in obj) {
                          ^

TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_id' in ./config
    at model.Document.$__buildDoc (/home/meryem/DevStuff/code/job-
tracker-capstone-app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:212:27)
    at model.Document (/home/meryem/DevStuff/code/job-tracker-
capstone-app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:61:20)
    at model.Model (/home/meryem/DevStuff/code/job-tracker-capstone-
app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:46:12)
    at new model (/home/meryem/DevStuff/code/job-tracker-capstone-
app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3671:13)
    at model (/home/meryem/DevStuff/code/job-tracker-capstone-
app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3669:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/meryem/DevStuff/code/job-tracker-
capstone-app/server.js:5:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
    at startup (node.js:148:18)
    at node.js:405:3

TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_id' in body-parser
    at model.Document.$__buildDoc (/home/meryem/DevStuff/code/job-
tracker-capstone-app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:212:27)
    at model.Document (/home/meryem/DevStuff/code/job-tracker-
capstone-app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:61:20)
    at model.Model (/home/meryem/DevStuff/code/job-tracker-capstone-
app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:46:12)
    at new model (/home/meryem/DevStuff/code/job-tracker-capstone-
app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3671:13)
    at model (/home/meryem/DevStuff/code/job-tracker-capstone-
app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3669:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/meryem/DevStuff/code/job-tracker-
capstone-app/server.js:4:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
    at startup (node.js:148:18)
    at node.js:405:3

TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_id' in mongoose
    at model.Document.$__buildDoc (/home/meryem/DevStuff/code/job-
tracker-capstone-app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:212:27)
    at model.Document (/home/meryem/DevStuff/code/job-tracker-
capstone-app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:61:20)
    at model.Model (/home/meryem/DevStuff/code/job-tracker-capstone-
app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:46:12)
    at new model (/home/meryem/DevStuff/code/job-tracker-capstone-
app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3671:13)
    at model (/home/meryem/DevStuff/code/job-tracker-capstone-
app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3669:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/meryem/DevStuff/code/job-tracker-
capstone-app/server.js:6:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
    at startup (node.js:148:18)
    at node.js:405:3
```

Please help.

Comment: OK, I just figured it out. Obviously the line `var require = require('./models/user');` is a giant typo and the source of my problems, plus I had app.listen in the server.js twice. I fixed those two things and everything is running fine now.